# Does max-pooling increase the receptive field?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution, pooling

I'm new in deep learning.

when applying convolution on the image , the receptive field is increased but when applying max pooling on the image, I don't know the receptive field is increasing or keep

for example 
there's an image that has a shape (11,11)
when applying convolution that has filters shape (3,3), stride=1 on the image, the output receptive field has 3
but when apply max pooling on the image, I don't know whether the receptive field is 1 or 3.

please Somebody tell me the answer.
thank you!